# How to make content float above page/popup not working

Tags: php, html, css, popup

I have been building a feedback script that can be added to any site. It works perfectly on a basic html page. However, I decided to put it onto our homepage and then things started to break. First off, the button to launch the tool shows behind other elements on the page. Second, it doesn't even work. Can anyone tell me how to fix these? I've tried top:xxxx; and that hasn't worked.

Thank you so much!

Austin

LIVE SITE: https://myhexa.co

BASIC HTML PREVIEW: https://myhexa.co/feedback/preview.html

Comment: Please go read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add css to `.feedback_form_button` element.

```
// To make button and form come on top of every thing.
.feedback_form_button, .feedback_form_window{
  z-index: 999
}
```

**Update:**
for having a non better view and focus try to create an overlay or can also do something like below :

create a div with any class within html of main page for eg. `<div class="test"></div>`
and add css something like below :

```
.test{
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
display: inherit;
z-index: 998; // should be less than zindex of button
background: red; // change according to your theme
position: fixed;
top: 0;
opacity: 0.9; // change according to your need.value in >=0 or <= 1
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Your css worked and it's now working properly!

Comment: @HexaTechnologies You are most welcome. If it worked do accept answer so that it might help other. :)

Comment: Thanks for the new code. It works, I just have to figure out how to display it on the whole page, as it's only showing in the iframe. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just set the z-index property of both the Feedback button and the popup to any value above 10 (as some section on your website use z-index:10) so just set the z-index property and it should work.